# Making A Sprite Bounce Off The Edge

Tags: java, android, libgdx, 2d-games

I'm trying to make a sprite bounce off the edge of the screen when it is less than 0. Right now it just zooms across the screen into the void. Here is my code-note that CentipedeBody is a class that extends Sprite. In the `render` method I call `ex.update();` which is an object of the class.   Then in between the `batch.begin()` and `batch.end()` I have   `batch.draw(ex,ex.getPosition().x,ex.getPosition().y,ex.getSize().x,ex.getSize().y);`

```
public class CentipedeBody extends Sprite
{
   public CentipedeBody(TextureRegion image,Vector2 position,Vector2 size)  {

      super(new TextureRegion(image));

      this.position = position;
      this.size=size;
      bounds=new Rectangle(position.x,position.y,8,8);
      left=true;
   }

  public void update() {

        bounds.set(getPosition().x,getPosition().y,8,8);

        if (left==true) {
           position.x-=(.5f);
            up=false;
            down=false;
            right=false;
            left=true;
        }

        if (right==true) {
            position.x+=.5f;
            left=false;
            right=true;
            down=false;
            up=false;
        }
        if (down==true) {

            position.y-=(.5f);
            right=false;
            left=false;
            down=true;
            up=false;

            if(position.x<0)
            {
                left=false;
                right=true;
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: According to your code snippet only `if(left){ }` executed so your sprite move left only

Comment: So how would I have `if(right)` execute? For the final game, I want the sprite to travel left, hit the edge of the screen, go down a bit, and then go right to the other edge, and repeat. Right now I just want to at least get it do bounce off the edges.

Comment: Could we do some type of tile collision with the tile by the edge of the screen?

Comment: I m not able to understand `go down a bit` ? what you achieve by this. ?

Comment: I am making a Centipede type game, I want this sprite to go down a row once it hits an edge and switch directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why bounds in your child class, `Sprite` having already bounds, use that if you're interested in collision with other objects. Same for position and for size, I don't think you need these extra data member in your Child class, use parent `x`,`y` for position and `width` and `height` for dimension.

```
public class CentipedeBody extends Sprite {

    enum State{
        LEFT,RIGHT,DOWN
    }

    State currentState,previousState ;

    public static final float DOWN_MOVEMENT=50;
    public float downMovCounter;
    public float speed;

    public CentipedeBody(TextureRegion image, Vector2 position, Vector2 size) {
        super(new TextureRegion(image));
        setPosition(position.x,position.y);
        setSize(size.x,size.y);
        currentState=State.LEFT;
        previousState=State.LEFT;
        speed=50;
    }

    public void update() {

        float delta=Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if(currentState ==State.LEFT){
            setPosition(getX()-speed*delta,getY());
            if(getX()<0) {
                previousState=currentState;
                currentState = State.DOWN;
            }
        }

        if(currentState ==State.RIGHT){
            setPosition(getX()+speed*delta,getY());
            if(getX()> Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-getWidth()) {
                previousState=currentState;
                currentState = State.DOWN;
            }
        }

        if(currentState ==State.DOWN){
            setPosition(getX(),getY()+speed*delta);
            downMovCounter++;
            if(downMovCounter>DOWN_MOVEMENT){
                downMovCounter=0;
                currentState =previousState==State.LEFT?State.RIGHT:State.LEFT;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

In render method

```
batch.begin();
batch.draw(centipedeBody,centipedeBody.getX(),centipedeBody.getY(),centipedeBody.getWidth(),centipedeBody.getHeight());
batch.end();
centipedeBody.update();
```

May be you need bounds, size and position in `CentipedeBody`, I can't judge your game requirement by one class code so you can easily integrate your variable in my code.

Comment: Thanks for your help but do you know why my sprite is moving diagonally? Remember my coordinate system is based on the cell's x and y.

Comment: moving diagonally ? how ? may be you're missing something.

Comment: You are amazing! My problem was that I realized in my tile map the y axis is pointing up, not down.

Comment: I understand most of the code except what does this if statement do `if(currentState==State.Down)` I am a bit new to enums.

Comment: enum is just a constant, I m checking a condition whenever currentState is `State.Down` move my sprite vertically otherwise horizontally.

Comment: I just upvoted your answers, for some reason the sprite does not bounce off the right edge of the screen so I'll probably recheck your code and work on it.

Comment: ya sure find the problem, Let me know If you're not able to resolve the problem.

Comment: I fixed it, I changed it to `getX()> 19` because that is the amount of cells in a row

Comment: Great, Glad to hear that

Comment: How would I make the sprite go down exactly one cell every time it hits an edge? Is this possible with delta time? I also don't want it to 'jump' to it the cell and to instead move it based on the speed but only going down one cell.